# Unbelievable: newly created partition automatically get formatted to vfat or ext4 and labeled to 'uefi-boot' or 'cloudimg-rootfs'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

On a linux server, I use PXE boot to load an ubuntu bionic, then create partition on local disk,
the unbelievable thing happened,
no matter what tool(sgdisk, parted) I used to create partition,
the newly created partition will be automatically

- formatted to vfat if it is small
- labeled to 'uefi-boot' if it is small, or 'cloudimg-rootfs'

```
root@:server1~# sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all && partprobe /dev/sda && lsblk /dev/sda
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk

root@server1:~# parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart P1 ext3 1MiB 8MiB
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

root@server1:~# partprobe /dev/sda && udevadm settle && lsblk /dev/sda && sh -c 'blkid /dev/sda*'
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0    7M  0 part
/dev/sda: PTUUID="f6e23816-0f58-4fa1-88a7-9663274d21b4" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="uefi-boot" UUID="CF08-DFE8" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="P1" PARTUUID="e5a560cd-4f40-4771-a219-771f3ed061a1"
```

See the `uefi-boot` in last line?

Same if I use sgdisk,

```
root@server1:~# sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all && partprobe /dev/sda && lsblk /dev/sda
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk

root@server1:~# sgdisk /dev/sda --new=3:4080:10000
Creating new GPT entries.
Information: Moved requested sector from 4080 to 2048 in
order to align on 2048-sector boundaries.
The operation has completed successfully.

root@server1:~# partprobe /dev/sda && udevadm settle && lsblk /dev/sda && sh -c 'blkid /dev/sda*'
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─sda3   8:3    0  3.9M  0 part
/dev/sda: PTUUID="4e2442b2-632a-43d5-9bf4-01d2fd21ce00" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="uefi-boot" UUID="CF08-DFE8" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7f564a33-855e-468f-a69e-1467974bb8df"
```

the partition start position and end position matters, if I specify the size quite large, then it will become 'cloudimg-rootfs' label, wow!

```
root@server1:~# sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all && partprobe /dev/sda && lsblk /dev/sda
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk

root@server1:~# sgdisk /dev/sda --new=3:1052672:3749640191
Creating new GPT entries.
The operation has completed successfully.

root@server1:~# partprobe /dev/sda && udevadm settle && lsblk /dev/sda && sh -c 'blkid /dev/sda*'
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─sda3   8:3    0  1.8T  0 part
/dev/sda: PTUUID="dd1266c5-e82b-4027-a423-94d7acd5b0d5" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="b000940e-c4fa-46d5-83bf-6cbef593300e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3b5806e1-3789-4caa-807f-8b9c7257009b"
```

I have confirmed that in normal linux box, this issue does not exist.

Maybe it is because some udev rules, still checking.

Anyone have this issue?

EDIT: for anyone who want have a try, run

```
sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all && partprobe /dev/sda && lsblk /dev/sda
sgdisk /dev/sda --new=3:4080:10000
partprobe /dev/sda && udevadm settle && lsblk /dev/sda && sh -c 'blkid /dev/sda*'
```

EDIT2: originally, I found a grub_bios partition has been auto formatted to vfat, causing problem. So I did the above test.

```
root@server1:~# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="uefi-boot" UUID="4DC8-5F56" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="bios_grub" PARTUUID="5d073c88-54aa-4b75-9eb8-baf62cde6cbd"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="uefi-boot" UUID="A224-71F4" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="efi" PARTUUID="9a315cf9-413f-406b-8830-373630d7ebba"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="0a5121c4-256d-4a87-96e4-8b7ec5b8a2d5" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="root" PARTUUID="6786acc3-20b9-4f07-881a-5ddb1dd38f7a"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be too surprising...

I expect that you've already got these two filesystems on this disk, and are you in fact seeing them.

Don't forget that tools like `parted` / `sgdisk` / `fdisk` will only edit the partition table, and won't touch any of the rest of the disk... When you "*delete*" a partition (or the partition table), you're really just wiping out the *location and size* of the partition, not wiping a filesystem.

You've never called one of the `mkfs.*` family, so I wouldn't expect for a filesystem to be created for you in this instance.

---

For example, the disk stats like this:

[image: initial disk layout, partition table and two partitions/filesystems]

You run `sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all`, and all you're really doing is wiping out the partition table:

> -Z, --zap-all
>
> Zap (destroy) the GPT and MBR data structures and then exit. This option
> works much like -z, but as it wipes the MBR as well as the GPT, it's more
> suitable if you want to repartition a disk after using this option, and
> completely unsuitable if you've already repartitioned the disk.

The partition table is gone, but the data is still on the disk.

[image: no partition table, but two filesystems are still present]

When you subsequently create a partition again, if it happens to line up with existing data, then you'll be able to access the filesystems as they were before:

```
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart P1 ext3 1MiB 8MiB
```

[image: new partition table, with one partition alogning with an existing filesystem]

**NOTE:** the new partition may be smaller than the filesystem, in which case fingerprinting it may work, but you may be unable to mount the filesystem, or may run into errors while accessing the content. A partition that is the same size or larger will always be able to access the filesystem.

---

In your second example, please be aware that your operation didn't complete as you'd hoped - specifically, your requested start sector of 4080 was *changed to 2048* to maintain alignment... i.e: this partition is actually *in the same place* as the first example you gave.

```
root@server1:~# sgdisk /dev/sda --new=3:4080:10000 --typecode=3:ef02
Creating new GPT entries.
Information: Moved requested sector from 4080 to 2048 in
order to align on 2048-sector boundaries.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Try wiping the first ~100MiB of your disk and trying your steps again:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=100
```

Comment: no, I create partition in new position than old one, but still get auto formatted.

Comment: and I did not called mkfs.* on those partitions.

Comment: Please see the last section of my answer - you didn't actually create the partition in a different place... you asked for that, but the tool fixed your mistake. The result is that the partition is _in the same place_ as before. There is no "_auto formatting_" going on here.

Comment: thank you very much! I know what you mean, I have been always thinking so, but I changed several random position to create partition, still get auto formatted, hope it is just a coincidence, maybe the position will be rounded to same position previously used.

Comment: ... try `4096` instead of `4080`, I expect you'll find that this isn't true. Also try wiping the first 100MiB, as mentioned in my edit.

Comment: mysterious things is that I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=1000` then did the test,  should be enough to clear those formatted file system.  Besides, I will never format a grub_bios raw partition, but now the grub_bios raw parition get formatted to vfat, and labled to 'uefi-boot', see what I have added to original post.

Comment: `dd` has a default block size (`bs=512`)... multiply this with your `count=1000`, and you'll see that you're only wiping the first ~500KiB of the disk. Given that the first partition starts at 2MiB, you have again not actually done what you think you have.

Comment: thank you so much. All cleared. I should zero more data, what a dumb.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem was already there. You only created a partition table entry pointing at it.

Similarly, your `sgdisk /dev/sda --zap-all` did not actually delete any data – only the pointers. And if your new partition begins at exactly the same sector as the old partition did, you're going to find exactly the same data as well.

(Note how your blkid command keeps reporting the same "UUID=" every time.)

You need to use something like `wipefs --all /dev/sda?*` before deleting partitions; this still won't actually delete data, but it will at least destroy the filesystem (by making it unidentifiable).